# How to encrypt using a RSA certificate in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, encryption, certificate, public-key, mpesa

I am going through [some docs](https://developer.safaricom.co.ke/Documentation) where I am required to encrypt some data using a certificate. The docs say

> Encrypt the array with the M-Pesa public key certificate. Use the RSA
> algorithm, and use PKCS #1.5 padding (not OAEP), and add the result to
> the encrypted stream.

Then it goes on to say:

> Convert the resulting encrypted byte array into a string using base64
> encoding. The resulting base64 encoded string is the security
> credential.

So my questions are:

1. How do I achieve this in nodejs?
2. I have [read that](https://superuser.com/a/620124/1133247):

> A certificate contains a public key. The certificate, in addition to
> containing the public key, contains additional information such as
> issuer, what the certificate is supposed to be used for, and other
> types of metadata.

.  What is the advantage of encrypting with a certificate as opposed to just using a public key? Or is it the same thing?

Comment: The first question is too broad - try this yourself. Yes, this is the same as "just using  a public key". The certificate contains information about the subject (in this case M-Pesa), how long the cert / key is valid and other meta information alongside the key. It also contains a signature, which is commonly used to *establish trust* in the key / information. Without trust you don't know for sure who has sent you the key after all.

Comment: When I asked how do I achieve this in nodejs I was asking do I just write the function as if I am encrypting using a public key?

Comment: `crypto.publicEncrypt()` can also process a certificate. Alternatively, `crypto.createPublicKey()` can be used to export the public key from the certificate and then encryption can be done with `crypto.publicEncrypt()`. In both cases the certificate has to be PEM encoded (-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----...).

Comment: The certificates are downloaded via an HTTPS link, so in a sense they gain some trust that way. The certificates themselves are long expired, and signed by an internal CA whose certificate is not available. So in this case, effectively, there's nothing useful about the certificate except for the public key it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Mpesa, you can either [use their website to generate the SecurityCredential](https://developer.safaricom.co.ke/TestCredentials), or refer to the following implementation through Node:

https://github.com/Wanyeki/node-mpesa-encryption/blob/main/src/password%20encrypt.js